# How to make cloth animation with bones?

Tags: animation

I would like to have cloth animation made in Blender and use it in Unity. I thought I will use the cloth modifier, then save the .blender file, import in unity and that's it. Nope. Only the actual frame gets loaded. So I thought I will try different aproach, but my skills in blender are not sufficient and I found no good information on the net so far - so I decided to ask experts :P.

Let's say, I have a plane and I want a flag animation with that. I break it down into like 20x20 pieces, and I make it to have like 20x20 bones as well pointing from pole towards to the end of the flag. I want to have blender to animate the bones like the cloth animator would do. How can I do this with this existing armature?

Comment: Something, like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xY55vbLeUZc

Comment: Five years too late, but: 1. Thank you for the video provided, it gave me a starting idea for what I aim to do
2. The tutorial below is very good for starting rigging an object (the concepts are applied to a character body, but you can just as well apply them to a plane) https://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-basic-low-poly-character-rig-in-blender--cg-16955